# How to load custom view in UIStoryBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am interested to write my custom view, so I created the following xib file:

[image]

This is the definition file:

```
- (void)_baseInit {
    NSLog(@"Unseen View loaded");
    [self addSubview:[self activityIndicator]];
    [self activityIndicator].alpha = 1.0;
    [self activityIndicator].frame = CGRectMake(round(([self imageView].frame.size.width - 25) / 2),
                                                round(([self imageView].frame.size.height - 25) / 2), 25, 25);
    [self activityIndicator].hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self showIndicator];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [self imageView].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [[self imageView] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self _baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        [self _baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I tried to hook it up in my story board:

[image: x]

And I have my MainViewController call this during viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.unseenView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UnseenView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.unseenView.delegate = self;
```

Unfortunately, nothing is showing up in my simulator **literally nothing, not even the text labels**. 
[image]

However I am seeing the following log messages:

```
2013-02-20 17:37:58.929 Giordano.iPhone[66857:c07] Unseen View loaded
2013-02-20 17:37:58.934 Giordano.iPhone[66857:c07] Unseen View loaded
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are preparing your view correctly, but you are not adding it to the view hierarchy. in the `viewDidLoad` code you need to add this line:

```
[self.view addSubview:unseenView];
```

Comment: You are my savior. However, I notice the following: 1. The view is truncated at the bottom (possibly due to my tab bar item), 2. I can't click on this new view. Do you know why?

Comment: @disappearedng TabBar would definitely truncate the view. You may want to add a simulated tab bar on the "simulated metrics" page to the bottom of your xib file to see how the actual view would look on a screen with a tab bar. The interaction should work, assuming that the class from which you load the view (i.e. the `owner:self` parameter in the call of `loadNibNamed`) is of the type to which you made the connections in the nib file. Here is a [link to a related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3078013/335858).

Comment: I deleted the UnseenView in storyboard and I still see the subview being added. Is there anyway to say "Whatever view you have here in the storyboard, replace that view with this subview such that the position and size matches?"

Comment: @disappearedng Unfortunately, you would need to do the resizing manually. Find the subview from the storyboard (e.g. give it a tag 123, and use `old = [self.view viewWithTag:123]`). Copy that view's frame parameters to the frame parameters of your new view. Call `[old removeFromSuperview]`, and then add the new view as a subview.